# How do I resolve this "'log_reg_model_test_perf' is not defined"?

Tags: logistic-regression

How do I resolve this "'log_reg_model_test_perf' is not defined" The code I used is :

```py
# testing performance comparison

models_test_comp_df = pd.concat(
    [
        log_reg_model_test_perf.T,
        log_reg_model_test_perf_threshold_auc_roc.T,
        log_reg_model_test_perf_threshold_curve.T,
    ],
    axis=1,
)
models_test_comp_df.columns = [
    "Logistic Regression-default Threshold (0.5)",
    "Logistic Regression-0.37 Threshold",
    "Logistic Regression-0.42 Threshold",
]

print("Test set performance comparison:")
models_test_comp_df
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-8560a1f9b155> in <module>()
      3 models_test_comp_df = pd.concat(
      4     [
----> 5         log_reg_model_test_perf.T,
      6         log_reg_model_test_perf_threshold_auc_roc.T,
      7         log_reg_model_test_perf_threshold_curve.T,

NameError: name 'log_reg_model_test_perf' is not defined
```

Comment: You are referring to a variable called `log_reg_model_test_perf`, which you have not defined in your code. Make sure you either define a variable with this name or change the name to a variable you do have defined.

Comment: Thanks but I am new to python. Can you assist with the definition?

Comment: In Python, you have to define variables which perform certain operation / hold some calculated value. In your case, looking at the code snippet in the original post, it's hard to find the variable 'log_reg_model_test_perf' definition. I am assuming that the code that you posted is the complete code and the error screenshot pertains to only that code snippet. In order to resolve this, please add the followinr /something similar before your model_test_comp_df step.  log_reg_model_test_perf = *here is the code for the obtaining the test performance /confusion matrix of log reg model*

Comment: @user138567 maybe you can post your entire code, if you haven't already, that way we can have a look at it.